# mnist-score for GANs on mnist data-set returns a logits tensor of [batch, 10]

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I use [this code](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/gan/mnist/util.py) to calculate mnist-score (inception score).
the function `mnist_score` returns the score as a tensor. how can i convert it to float?

```
def mnist_score(images, graph_def_filename=None, input_tensor=INPUT_TENSOR,
                output_tensor=OUTPUT_TENSOR, num_batches=1):
  """Get MNIST logits of a fully-trained classifier.
  Args:
    images: A minibatch tensor of MNIST digits. Shape must be
      [batch, 28, 28, 1].
    graph_def_filename: Location of a frozen GraphDef binary file on disk. If
      `None`, uses a default graph.
    input_tensor: GraphDef's input tensor name.
    output_tensor: GraphDef's output tensor name.
    num_batches: Number of batches to split `generated_images` in to in order to
      efficiently run them through Inception.
  Returns:
    A logits tensor of [batch, 10].
  """
  images.shape.assert_is_compatible_with([None, 28, 28, 1])

  graph_def = _graph_def_from_par_or_disk(graph_def_filename)
  mnist_classifier_fn = lambda x: tfgan.eval.run_image_classifier(  # pylint: disable=g-long-lambda
      x, graph_def, input_tensor, output_tensor)

  score = tfgan.eval.classifier_score(
      images, mnist_classifier_fn, num_batches)
  score.shape.assert_is_compatible_with([])

  return score
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing to note is that the inception score has little meaning on MNIST. It calculates the logits and looks at the distribution of those logits. However, numbers are not even classes in ImageNet so using a pre trained net will result in arbitrary output.

Apart from this you can evaluate tensors in tensorflow using either a session and running that session with `sess.run(score)` or if you are within a session you can just use `score.eval()`. Depending on if images is a placeholder or a fixed tensor you might need to feed your images into the method as well.